# TSQL apply condition if the query is not null

Tags: t-sql

I have this SP in T-SQL

```
DECLARE @DATA_INIZIO AS DATE
DECLARE @DATA_FINE AS DATE

/*CODE TO POPULATE @DATA_INIZIO E @DATA_FINE*/

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM AA_V_ATS_Richieste R
WHERE R.IdTipoRichiesta = 1 AND R.DataInizio>= @DATA_INIZIO
AND R.DataFine <= @DATA_FINE
```

Now @DATA_INIZIO and @DATA_FINE can be null or not null. If there is a way to change my query and if @Data_inizio is not null then execute this condition and if @Data_Inizio is null, not execute this condition ?

Comment: You could just add a case statement into your where clause if you are saying you want to filter differently based on whether or not a value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM AA_V_ATS_Richieste R
WHERE
    R.IdTipoRichiesta = 1
    AND (R.DataInizio >= @DATA_INIZIO OR @DATA_INIZIO IS NULL)
    AND (R.DataFine <= @DATA_FINE OR @DATA_FINE IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "execute this condition" you mean execute the query you could do it a couple ways.

Inside a stored proc (or anywhere you can apply T-SQL procedural logic (e.g. IF/THEN/ELSE/WHILE) you could simply do this:

```
IF @DATA_INIZIO IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM AA_V_ATS_Richieste R
  WHERE R.IdTipoRichiesta = 1 
  AND   R.DataInizio >= @DATA_INIZIO
  AND   R.DataFine   <= @DATA_FINE;
END; -- note: You don't need the BEGIN/END, just including for readability
```

As part of an inline query you can create a 'Startup Predicate' in you WHERE clause like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM AA_V_ATS_Richieste R
  WHERE R.IdTipoRichiesta = 1 
  AND   R.DataInizio >= @DATA_INIZIO
  AND   R.DataFine   <= @DATA_FINE
) subquery(ttl)
WHERE @DATA_INIZIO IS NOT NULL;
```

If @DATA_INIZIO is null, nothing will be returned.